# The redirecting constructor can't have a field initialiser

Tags: dart

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  String url;

  Product(
    this.id,
    this.name,
  );

  Product.fromMap(Map data)
      : url = data['url'], // error
        this(data['id'], data['name']);
}
```

How can I assign value to `url` in named constructor, I don't want to use method to get this done.

Comment: You mean, like this: ```class Product { String url; Product(url): this.url = url}``` ?

Comment: @tomerpacific Not sure what was that, I need to assign url a value using `data` passed to `Product.fromMap()`

Comment: You said : ```How can I assign value to url in named constructor```. The comment was in response to that.